# T-SQL Union, but exclude results from one table based on another without using a temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I am looking to UNION two select statements, but have it so that the second select excludes some results if the first select contains certain records without using a temp table

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
select customernumber, name into #tempCustomer1 from customers1

select customernumber, name from #tempCustomer1 
UNION
select customernumber, name from customers2 
where customernumber not in (select customernumber from #tempCustomer1)

order by customernumber
```

Is it possible to do this without a temp table?

Answer (score 2):

Your query with `UNION` should be doing exactly what you want cause Union discards the duplicate rows from the result set. So, you can just say

```
select customernumber, name from customers1

UNION

select customernumber, name from customers2
```

Per your comment, you can use a inline query to achieve the same without using temporary table like

```
SELECT * FROM
(
select customernumber, name from customers1

UNION

select customernumber, name from customers2
) tab
WHERE customernumber NOT IN (select customernumber from customers1)
ORDER BY customernumber
```

Comment: What if the customernumber and name combination is different.  For example in table 1 I have customer number 1 with name 'john', but in table two I have customer number 1 with name 'johnny'.  I want to be able to filter out the 'johnny' record from table 2.

Comment: That's kind of custom filtering, in which case you should be doing what you are currently having. A bit modified of your query, see edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what your desired end result is, but to answer your question *Is it possible to do this without a temp table?* Yes it is - you could do this:

```
select customernumber, name from customers1
UNION
(
select customernumber, name from customers2 
where customernumber not in (select customernumber from customers1)
) 
order by customernumber
```

This will return a set made up from the rows in customers1 and customers2 with the customer1 ids removed from customers2, I think this is what you want.

If you want to get rid of duplicate rows, this is done by the`UNION`since you didn't add the`ALL`option to it.

With this test setup:

```
declare @customers1 table (customernumber int, name char)
declare @customers2 table (customernumber int, name char)

insert @customers1 values (1,'a'),(2,'b')
insert @customers2 values (3,'d'),(4,'e'),(1,'f')

select customernumber, name from @customers1 
UNION
(
select customernumber, name from @customers2 
where customernumber not in (select customernumber from @customers1)
) 
order by customernumber
```

The output would be:

```
customernumber  name
1   a
2   b
3   d
4   e
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `EXCEPT` keyword in place of the `UNION` to get the simplest syntax

```
 SELECT Direction,[Foo] FROM DEV1.dbo.OUTB
 EXCEPT
 SELECT Direction,[Foo] FROM UAT1.dbo.OUTB
```